# dispatching redux action in middleware cause unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-middleware, redux-devtools

I am trying to understand how redux middleware works, during my experiment  I have noticed that dispatching an action from redux middleware may result in an unexpected behavior.

I will try to explain the problem by simulating file upload as follow:

we have 3 actions:

```
const setProgress = (progress) => ({ type: SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS, progress });
const setThumbnail = (thumbnail) => ({ type: SET_THUMBNAIL, thumbnail });
const calculateTotal = () => ({ type: CALCULATE_TOTAL });
```

Middleware to calculate total:

```
export const testMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === 'CALCULATE_TOTAL') {
    return next(action);
  }
  const result = next(action);
  store.dispatch(calculateTotal());
  return result;
};
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  progress: 0,
  total: 0,
  thumbnail: ''
};
export function uploadReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS:
      state.progress = action.progress;
      return { ...state };
    case SET_THUMBNAIL:
      state.thumbnail = action.thumbnail;
      return { ...state };
    case CALCULATE_TOTAL:
      state.total += state.progress * 5;
      return { ...state };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here is the code for simulating file upload:

```
  let cnt = 0;
  // simulate upload progress
  const setNewProgress = () => {
    cnt += 2;
    if (cnt > 5) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
      store.dispatch(setProgress(cnt * 2));
      setNewProgress();
    }, 1000);
  };
  setNewProgress();
  // simulate thumbnail generating
  setTimeout(() => {
    store.dispatch(setThumbnail('blob:http://thumbnail.jpg'));
  }, 2500);
```

Here is the sequence of events:

the first action works as intended and sets the progress value:

[image]

the problem starts from here; thumbnail suppose to be set by 'setThumbnail' but devtools shows that it has been set by 'calculateTotal', and every dispatch after that is mismatched:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? is it by design? how can I dispatch an action in middleware without causing above problem?

Comment: your `uploadReducer` is not pure, i.e. it is directly modifying state (e.g. `state.progress = action.progress;`). reducers should only return the new state and not modify existing state (see this [example](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-more-actions)). You need to do it like this: `case CALCULATE_TOTAL: return { ...state, total: state.progress * 5 }` maybe this is causing the problem. otherwise your reducer, actions and middleware looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unexpected behavior may be cause by your `uploadReducer` not being [pure](https://redux.js.org/introduction/threeprinciples#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions), i.e. it is directly operating on your state (e.g. `state.progress = action.progress;`). Reducers [should](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-more-actions) only return the new state and not modify existing state injected into your reducer by redux. hence, your reducer needs to look like this:

```
export function uploadReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_UPLOAD_PROGRESS:
      return { ...state, progress: action.progress };
    case SET_THUMBNAIL:
      return { ...state, thumbnail: action.thumbnail };
    case CALCULATE_TOTAL:
      return { ...state, total: state.total + state.progress * 5 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

> how can I dispatch an action in middleware without causing above problem?

Your middleware looks fine (you are correctly preventing recursion and also returning the `next()` result (which is not needed in your example but still makes sense in a real application). Your actions look good as well (a style remark: You could wrap your action's payload in a `payload` property, which is a common [convention](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action)).

Comment: thank you for the help,  the problem is solved, this pure stuff is very confusing :)

Comment: @sam yeah I know. the reason reducers need to be pure is that redux is then able to properly calculate state updates and forward them via the `connect` HoC to your components. – If this solved your problem, then please also mark my answer as accepted, thanks :)

Comment: sure, thanks for all the explanation, now it's making more sense, I began to understand how redux works.